# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to check if the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$$
converges or not using the integral test.

$$\int^L\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x!}}dx\sim\int^L\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x^xe^{-x}}}dx=\int^L x^{-x/2}e^{3x/2}dx=\int^Le^{-x\ln x/2}e^{3x/2}dx$$
I don't know How to check the convergence of the integral. Please Help me with this.

Comment: Do you have to use the integral test? I think it's perhaps easier to check it if you don't.

Comment: The problem here is that you need an extension of  $x!$ to positive reals (the Gamma function works) but the the integral becomes cumbersome. There are other ways to do it to avoid this.

Comment: The root test would give you a quite way to decide convergence in this particular problem.

Comment: Just say $$\frac{e^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \sim \text{constant} \times \frac{e^{3n/2}}{(\sqrt[4]{n})^{2n+1}} \lt \text{constant} \times \frac{e^{3n/2}}{e^{2n+1}} = \text{constant} \times e^{-n/2}$$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Try showing, as a lemma, that for any $a$, $n!$ is eventually more than $a^n$.   You don't need Stirling for this, just use the product definition.  Now choose $a = e^4$ for example...

Comment: @daruma In the exercise, it's written using both ratio and integral test to show if this converges or not.